# Spring Bean sessionFactory com erro NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0, wildfly, multi-tenancy

Bom dia.

Estou tentando fazer uma configuração no arquivo spring-jpa.xml para comportar uma arquitetura multitenancy separando cada cliente por Schema. Utilizo um dataSource que foi configurado no JBoss Wildfly para se conectar no banco de dados onde estão os schemas.

O que falta adicionar nas configurações?

> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Full stack trace:

```
11:26:23,712 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) [spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more

11:26:23,716 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more

11:26:23,733 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projectERP.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
11:26:23,946 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "projectERP.war" (runtime-name : "projectERP.war")
11:26:23,947 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectERP: Failed to start service
```

Spring-jpa.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dataSource"
    lookup-on-startup="true" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.package.*.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
            <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                value="com.package.security.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl" />
            <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
                value="com.package.security.MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="autodetectDataSource" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">

</persistence-unit>
```

MultiTenantIdentifierResolvImp.class:

```
package com.package.security;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String tenantResoloved = resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier();

        LOGGER.debug("Tenant Schema resolved by SchemaResolverAdmin " + tenantResoloved);

        return "public";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

MultiTenantConnectionProvider.class:

```
package com.package.security;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl implements
        MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9064120876236832566L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.class);  

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier)
            throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute(
                    "SET schema " + tenantIdentifier);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema ["
                            + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        return connection;

    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("SET schema " + tenantIdentifier);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema ["
                            + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Salve! Você está utilizando um `TransactionManager` local mesmo a aplicação sendo distribuída em um servidor de aplicação JEE. É possível você alterar para `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager`? Dessa forma você não precisa configurar o Hibernate dentro do contexto do Spring. O próprio *container*, no caso o Wildfly, faria a gestão do EM pra você via JNDI. Se for possível, dá um toque no comentário que eu coloco uma resposta pra você abordando esse método.

Comment: Uma pessoa favoritou a pergunta, então se você conseguisse colocar uma resposta abordando sobre isso pode colocar aqui mesmo com a solução do problema já encontrada para este erro não ocorrer (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salve!

Considerando que você *pode* trocar a implementação do `TransactionManager` da sua aplicação, eu sugiro a seguinte abordagem:

### applicatioContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
        jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dataSource"
        lookup-on-startup="true" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <!-- EM do container -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManager"
        jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/meu-em"
        lookup-on-startup="true" proxy-interface="javax.persistence.EntityManager" />

    <!-- TransactionManager do Container -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Repare que não há nenhuma configuração do `EntityManager` aqui. Como estamos utilizando o Wildfly, deixo pra ele criar. Só faço a referência ao JNDI. O Spring fará o restante.

### persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Using the example datasource set up by WildFly 8 For your application, 
            set up a managed datasource and use that instead -->
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/dataSource</jta-data-source>
        <!-- 
          ref.: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html
         -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
            <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.package.security.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl" />
            <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.package.security.MultiTenantIdentifierResolverImpl" />
            <!-- scan das suas entidades -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Como é o Wildfly que vai gerenciar o `EM` é preciso defini-lo no próprio container. Esse arquivo pode ficar no seu `classpath` e ser distribuído junto com a sua aplicação ou ser instalado como um módulo do Wildfly que será utilizado pela sua aplicação. Depende do seu cenário.

Agora é preciso fazer a referência do `EM` na sua aplicação Web para o Wildfly saber que você vai utilizar o recurso. No seu arquivo `web.xml`, adicione o seguinte:

```
<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/meu-em</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>persistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

Na sua camada de acesso à dados, faça referência ao `EntityManager` via injeção do Spring:

```
@Inject
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

Pode usar `@Autowire` se você não utiliza as interfaces comuns do JSR-330.

Eu não consigo testar aqui porque não tenho projeto com configuração via `xml`. Se der algum galho, avise nos comentários para eu poder acertar e te ajudar.

Como referência, eu tenho um [projeto no Github](https://github.com/ricardozanini/spring-config-dao) utilizando a configuração da camada de dados via classe (`@Configuration`).